# Is modulus a prime number important for non-symmetric cryptology?

Tags: rsa, group-theory

From this link
[Generation of a cyclic group of prime order](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/22716/generation-of-a-cyclic-group-of-prime-order/72980#72980)
we know how to generate a prime order group.

[image]

This illustrates why a prime order group is important.

But why is modulus a prime number also important?

In the theory of RSA, the modulus $N=pq$, and $\operatorname{totient}(N)=(p-1)(q-1)$， if we can find a factor $p'$ of $p-1$, then we can claim there is a $p'$ order sub-group? But it is not a modulus prime group, the $N$ is a composite number, is such a group useful?

Comment: In classical Diffie-Hellman, you work on the multiplicative group $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ where $p$ is prime. All computations are done modulo the prime $p$.

Comment: Another example is elliptic curve cryptography, which is often performed with an elliptic curve with x and y coordinates in the prime field $\Bbb Z_p$. Yet another is fast implementations of RSA signature and decryption (CRT-based), where the heaviest computations are performed modulo each prime dividing the public modulus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, such a group is useful. In particular, when $N= p\cdot q$ where $p,q$ are both strong primes (i.e. $p=2p'+1,q=2q'+1$ where $p',q'$ are also prime numbers).

Discrete logarithm in the prime order cyclic groups (order-$p'$ and order-$q'$) is believed to be hard. Such a group is called a group with hidden order.

A few examples of application: Fujisaki and Okamoto used this group to construct a [commitment scheme](https://www.iacr.org/cryptodb/data/paper.php?pubkey=1310). It has also been used in constructing a [zero-knowledge proof](https://www.iacr.org/archive/eurocrypt2000/1807/18070437-new.pdf) of an integer falls within an interval (range proof).

Note that security does not hold for any arbitrary $N$ (even if it has only two large prime factors), see this [paper](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-49649-1_18).

Comment: Thanks, these thoughts are very creative, I've downloaded the paper and looking at it.